# Closing chrome browser after tests with Appium? JAVA

Tags: java, google-chrome, crash, appium

I'm trying to find a way for me to close all tabs of chrome after performing certain tasks with Appium using Java, for example on Android. Is there a way I can do that? All tabs keep growing and growing and that causes the tests to crash.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to clear the application data using ADB:

```sh
adb shell pm clear com.android.chrome
```

You may do this as a precondition for your tests, for example somewhere in `@BeforeClass` or `@BeforeSuite` if you use TestNG. The side effect is that you have to accept terms and conditions upon chrome opening and click the `No thanks` button on the Sign-in to Chrome View. But this is not a big deal.

**Pros**: clean Chrome browser without any tabs and cache on every test run

**Cons**: some Chrome initialization is required every time (~5..10 seconds to perform)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try another approach as written here: https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/How+To%3A+Close+Tabs+in+Google+Chrome

Create a function (inside your app @BeforeSuite or @BeforeClass) that will simulate touch events of a mobile user that press a button to close all chrome tabs.